# Kotlin stream of file lines using Java8 Files.lines

Tags: string, kotlin, stream

There is used file with UTF8 encoding. The file is following:

```
41 18467
6334 26500
15724 19169
11478 29358
24464 26962
```

Processing of the following code prints empty lines:

```
private fun doTask(sPath: String) {
   Files.lines(Paths.get(sPath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
      .forEach{println()}
}
```

Help to fix the code. Is there good only-Kotlin solution without involving Java8 library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing blank lines because your `println()` call isn't being told to print anything. If you want to print each line, you'll have to pass `it` (the default argument in a lambda, if you don't specify one) along to `println`:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(sPath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    .forEach{println(it)}
```

You can also simplify this a bit, using Kotlin's `File.readLines()` extension, which defaults to UTF-8:

```
File(sPath).readLines().forEach { println(it) }
```

Comment: It can be simplified even further: `File(sPath).forEachLine{ println(it) }`.  (That's more efficient, too, and works with bigger files.)  (Similar cases can be simplified further still with a method reference, but you can't do that here as `println()` has several overloads, and there seems no way to resolve them yet.)

Comment: That's neat, I wasn't aware of `forEachLine()`!